# change window.status from iframe in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page which has an iFrame. Inside the iFrame I have a different application working. I tried to change the window.status using javascript but it doesn't work from iFrame. It still shows the status of parent application. Below is the code I tried from child application.

```
function UpdateWindowTimeOutStatus() {
//top.window.status = "Session will time out in: " + Display(30, 0);
//window.parent.status = "Session will time out in: " + Display(30, 0);
//parent.window.status = "Session will time out in: " + Display(30, 0);
//top.parent.window.status = "Session will time out in: " + Display(30, 0);
//top.parent.parent.window.status = "Session will time out in: " + Display(30, 0);
window.status = "";
```

}

This doesn't work out. I put a break point in the javascript and it changes the status when break point hits but when i run,  it rolls back to the parent window status.

What am i missing?

EDIT: The commented code is already tried code. Window.status is not the only thought i have tried.

Thanks

Comment: window.status is the iFrames's window. You need window.top.status to access the top window's status.

Comment: No, It doesn't work either :(

Comment: window.status was disabled a long time ago in all popular browsers to prevent link rollover destination spoofing.

Comment: @dandavis okay when i google i find window.status everywhere. Could you please suggest what to use instead of window.status?

Comment: it depends on what you want to use it for. for debugging, use console.log or document.title, for users, use a tooltip, a modal, a notification, or a status bar-looking fixed position element.

Comment: You can change the document title.